# EntityNotFoundException with joinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

i'm having a problem figuring out why my joinColumn is doing a request on my attribute even if its in lazy mode.
my entity contains this two attributes:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "classPK",updatable=false,insertable=false)
private Account account;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "classPK",updatable=false,insertable=false)
private User user;
```

The problem i'm having is that after the fetch of my query, i'm having a `EntityNotFoundException` for the account because he didn't found an accound with the id=20 in the table, because the 20 id is in user table. how can i fix that without using the NotFound annotation because it will do the Eager mode. i tried the postLoad method but it only worked with the user not with the account

Answer (score 0):

If you have some discriminator column that can help Hibernate determine which entity type is the target, you can use a single `@Any` mapping, but in general, this kind of mapping is simply broken. Either use two columns for the two associations with proper foreign keys, or use the discriminator any mapping approach.